# Bevel a circle in plane along curve path

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, bevel, extrude, 2d

Given a path (bézier curve) and a circle (black dot) as it follows

[image: Path and circle]

I'd like to extrude the circle along the curve such as it creates the following surface

[image: expected result]

Using the bevel tool with blender, this is the best I can get.
(Add>Curve>Bezier, Add>Curve>Circle, Bezier curve>Data>Geometry>Bevel, Rotate the circle in edit mode)

[image: blender screenshot]

I expect the edges to be smooth. Somehow [this person made it happen by mistake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200373/trying-to-bevel-a-circle-along-a-path-and-getting-a-flat-paperclip). But I can't figure how he did. Do you know how to fix that ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

just increase "resolution preview":

[image]